# Solving the wave equation under a Neumann boundary condition on the gradient at one point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation

This is my first question/contribution even though I have been following hot topics for a while, I have been confronted a to a problem recently and I don't really know how to address it.

This comes from acoustics, there is a consequent amount of literature around solving the wave equation under homogeneous Neumann condition on some boundaries. This represent the case of a sound wave propagating in a room with perfectly reflecting walls. One method for addressing this problem is the image source method where we construct a lattice from the source by reflecting though a list of walls.
This was done for an arbitrary polyhedral room in 1984 in a paper named "Extension of the image model to arbitrary polyhedra" by Jeffrey Borish.

Unfortunately he don't give proofs of his argument, just some intuition. I am currently researching on this and I would like to be able to prove his results, but I would like to also generalize the method for non closed rooms

So long story short, I end up been stuck solving the following equation for the pressure
$$\nabla^2 p({\bf x}) + k^2 p({\bf x}) = 0$$
Subject to
$$\nabla p({\bf y}) = {\bf q}$$
Where we know $k$, ${\bf q}$ and ${\bf y}$ (${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$ are vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$)
Of course as is, there might even not be a solution to this problem, I have been reading through section 6 of the book "Methods of Theoretical physics" which gave me some useful insight, in the end of section 6.2 he states the cases when the solution exists and about uniqueness. For my case, Hyperbolic equation with open boundaries, they state that we have insufficient information about the problem. So I may actually have a solution.

In the sane book section 6.3, he solve a lot of these kinds of equations but the boundaries condition always seems to be homogeneous. They are using an eigen decomposition of the problem, maybe it is possible to adapt this reasoning to my problem.
Finally I went through a substantial amount of literature on the subject but the boundaries conditions where almost always homogeneous. I also could not find a similar question here or somewhere else on the web.

So if any one have an idea about this I would be glad to discuss it.
I hope that this is clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I forgot to mention that in I also have boundaries conditions at infinite distance from the origin, the pressure is supposed to be zero.

EDIT 2 : I think the solution may actually be unique. The uniqueness should not depend on the choice of ${\bf q}$ or ${\bf y}$ and so we can probably just look at ${\bf y} = {\bf q} = {\bf 0}$. In this case if we use a eigen decomposition argument, we get that our eigen functions would be of the form $\cosh(a_{k,i} x_i)$ for $x_i$ the i'th coordinate of ${\bf x}$ and for any $a_{k,i}$, then we can express our pressure as 
$$p({\bf x}) = \sum_k \sum_i A_{k,i} \cosh(a_{k,i} x_i)$$
and
$$\nabla^2 p({\bf x}) = \sum_k \sum_i A_{k,i} a_{k,i}^2 \cosh(a_{k,i} x_i)$$
Now the next step is a bit unclear but I think that in order to have $\nabla^2 p({\bf x}) + k^2 p({\bf x}) = 0$, then we need to have $A_{k,i} a_{k,i}^2 + A_{k,i} k^2 =0$ for all $k$ and $i$. This can only be true if for all $k$ and $i$, $A_{k,i}=0$.
Does this reasoning makes sense ? And is way to generalize to any ${\bf q}$ ? Then generalizing to any ${\bf y}$ is trivial.

Comment: I want to point out two unclear aspects of your very interesting question. First, I do not understand in your gradient condition:in the form stated, if you know $\pmb{q}=\pmb{q}(\pmb{y})$ (i.e. as a function of y) then $$\nabla p(\pmb{y})=\pmb{q}\iff\nabla\cdot\nabla p(\pmb{y})=\nabla^2 p(\pmb{y})=\nabla\cdot\pmb{q}(\pmb{y})$$ and thus $$p(\pmb{y})=-\frac{1}{k^2}\nabla\cdot\pmb{q}(\pmb{y}),$$ while if $\pmb{q}=\mathrm{const}$ you have an incompatibility since in this case $\nabla^2 p(\pmb{y})=\pmb{0}$ an $p$ cannot be a solution of the Helmholtz equation.

Comment: Second, I do not understand how did you get the eigenfunctions by which you are expressing $p(\pmb{x})$: the usual eigenfunction solutions for the Helmhotz equation in a general 3D geometry are $$U_n(\pmb{x})=f_n(r)K_n\Big(\hat{\pmb{r}}\Big)$$ where $K_n$ are [spherical harmonics]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics), $f_n$ are [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) or [Hankel functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelFunction.html), $\Big(r,\hat{\pmb{r}}\Big)$ are the polar coordinates of $\pmb{x}$. Are you studying the problem inside a spcial domain?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear information. So what I meant by my condition on the gradient is that for some $\pmb{y}$, we fix the gradient, so the problem is equivalent up to a shift of the plane to solving :
$$\nabla^2 p(\pmb{x}) + k^2 p(\pmb{x}) = 0$$
subject to 
$$\nabla p(\pmb{0}) = \pmb{q}$$
for some vector $\pmb{q}$ that we know.
Hope this is a better formulation.
Regarding my last edit, you should ignore that, I realized too late that it did not satisfied the boundary conditions at $\infty$, so I should express that as Bessel and Hankel functions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I do not know how to deal with this problem, but I have a suggestion on how to rigorously prove the results of Borish. The paper of A. G. Kyurkchan, B. Ya. Sternin and V. E. Shatalov (1996) "*Singularities of continuation of wave fields*", Physics-Uspekhi, 1996, 39, 1221-1242, describes the approach developed by the authors in order to extend the method of images for the construction of the Green's function for Helmholtz equation to more complex than usual boundaries. Their approach is applicable to the Neumann Green's function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the paper. It seems they are using the Bessel functions that you mentioned in your second comment and I lack some intuition about those (I am not from physics or acoustics).
It seems to me that I may be able to express a solution to the [Helmholtz Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) as a linear combination of those.

Is there a way of expressing the gradient of those ? Or maybe I should express my gradient condition in the spherical coordinate ?

Comment: Reading our comments, I realized that your questions deserves more than few hints in a long list of comments, therefore I'll try to post a full answer in the week-end, but beware! I do not know an exact answer to your question, otherwise I would have already posted it: on the other hand I think I can guide you to find an answer by yourself, so I'll try to do this.

Comment: Then maybe you should I am actually interested in
$$\int_{\pmb{y}\in S_\epsilon} \frac{d}{d\pmb{n}} p(\pmb{z}+\pmb{y})dS$$
Where $\pmb{z}$ is known.
Where $S_\epsilon$ is the sphere of radius $\epsilon$ around $\pmb{0}$
I would like to show that this integral is only a function of the derivative in the direction of $\pmb{z}$. Also I am considering the problem where I know at $\pmb{0}$ the value of $p$ and it's derivative in the direction of $\pmb{z}$, for this problem we know the solution is unique and if then I can have no dependency in the integral on the density, then I'm done.

Comment: Is $\pmb{z}$ a point on the interior/exterior of  the sphere $S_\epsilon$ or could it also be on its boundary? And is $\pmb{y}$ on the interior or could also be on the boundary of it?

Comment: $\pmb{y}$ is always exterior, actually, I have a $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}$, $\pmb{y}$ is on $S_{\epsilon}$ and $\pmb{n}$ is a normalisation of $\pmb{y}$

Comment: Note that you have, by the [Gauss-Green (divergence) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem): $$
\int\limits_{S_\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{n}} p(\pmb{z+y})\mathrm{d}S_\boldsymbol{y} = \int\limits_{S_\epsilon}\nabla p(\pmb{z+y})\cdot \boldsymbol{n}\mathrm{d}S_\boldsymbol{y} =
\int\limits_{B_\epsilon}\nabla^2 p(\pmb{z+y})\mathrm{d}V_\boldsymbol{y} =
-\int\limits_{B_\epsilon} k^2 p(\pmb{z+y})\mathrm{d}V_\boldsymbol{y}.
$$ Then, since every integrable solution of the Helmholtz equation is real analytic, the integral goes to zero as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Yes I know, but the question is how it behaves with $\epsilon$.

If we take a look at the book "Fourier Acoustics - Sound Radiation and Nearfield Acoustical Holography" by "Earl G. Williams", Equation 8.29 can be used in my case:
$$
p(\pmb{z})=\int_{\pmb{y}\in S_\epsilon} \left[ G(\pmb{z}+\pmb{y}\mid \pmb{z}) \frac{d}{d\pmb{n}} p(\pmb{z}+\pmb{y})- p(\pmb{z}+\pmb{y})\frac{d}{d\pmb{n}}G(\pmb{z}+\pmb{y}\mid \pmb{z})\right]
$$

Where $G$ is the Green function in free field. So now when $\epsilon$ tends to zero the second term tends to zero (but it may be wrong), only the first remains

Comment: anyway, I am not allowed to disclose too much information about this since it is what I do for my internship and I have a NDA. But I will try to negotiate the right to finish the project on my own if I can't finish it on time. Then I will make a big post about all I have on the Image Source Method. I will put a link to my new post here.

Comment: Mmm, I think I have understand: you need a formula like the one in your last comments but involving the Neumann Green function instead of the Dirichlet's Green function. I'll arrange something in my answer, if this is viable.